# Returning multiple data frames from function "too many values to unpack" error

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe, return

I am trying to call a function and have it return 3 separate data frames.
I have 2 scripts - a driver script & a main script.

In my driver script I have something as follows:

```
 import pandas as pd
 finalA = pd.DataFrame()
 finalB = pd.DataFrame()
 finalC = pd.DataFrame()
 for week in allWeeks:
    date_start = week[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    date_end = week[1].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    try:
        a, b, c = function(start_date, end_date)
        finalA = finalA.append(a)
        finalB = finalB.append(b)
        finalC = finalC.append(c)`
    except Exception as e:
        _m = traceback.format_exc()
        logger.error(_m)
```

where a, b, c are data frames

then in my main script I have something as follows:

```
 def function(start_date, end_date):
    a = ...(constructing df)
    b = ...(constructing df)
    c = ...(constructing df)
    return a, b, c
```

however, I keep getting this whenever I run through the loop in my driver script:
"File "", line 118, in 
    a, b, c = function(date_start, date_end)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)"

I should also note that everything used to run successfully when I was only returning one dataframe, so it's not date errors or anything like that. it's looping through a set of weeks and calling the function each time and then appending the results to a bigger dataframe

Comment: I'm suspicious of the comma after c in your driver script.

Comment: that was a mistake on my part when I was writing this post.. there's no comma in my actual code. just updated post

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace. I don't think anything can be interpreted from the current code provided

Comment: There isn't anything else to the error other than what I already posted. that's all it says